# $(document).read() makes jQuery Validation Require Two Clicks

Tags: jquery, validation

I asked this question earlier on stackoverflow, but it's still vexing me. I found out the problem is that the jQuery validation code is inside of the document ready function. Because it's inside of another function it's only clicking through after the second click. So, I had the brilliant idea that I'd move it outside of the document ready, but now it's not even doing to validation when the button is clicked. My question is, how can I just call one function without having to put it inside of the ready function? I've seen people post things like, "this is simple". Yet, wherever I look the question seems to remain unanswered. I've seen other people use an async false and that does seem to work but its function is deprecated. My idea is that if there is some way to call document ready on the selector.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
function func1(field,message) {
$(field).hover(function() {
$('#submenu').stop().fadeIn();
$('#submenu').html(message);
}, function() {
$('#submenu').stop().fadeOut();
});
}
func1('#first_name','This is the first name field. Please type slowly and carefully.');
func1('#last_name','This is the last name field.');
func1('#username','Username may be letters and numbers.');
func1('#password','A password phrase is stronger than a single password. Try interspersing words with special characters to create a strong password phrase.');
func1('#email','Please insert a valid e-mail address.');
});
/*$('#signup').validate();*/
/* Testing remote email validation */
/* Change remote: to "php_validation_scripts/check_(name)_field.php" */
$('#signup').unbind('hover').validate({ rules: {
email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    rangelength:[1,50],
    remote: "php_validation_scripts/check_email_field.php"
    },
password: {
    required: true,
    rangelength:[15,100],
    remote: "php_validation_scripts/check_password_field.php"
    },
username: {
    required: true,
    rangelength:[6,18],
    remote: "php_validation_scripts/check_username_field.php"
},
last_name: {
    required: true,
    rangelength:[1,50],
    remote: "php_validation_scripts/check_last_name_field.php"
},
first_name: {
    required: true,
    rangelength:[1,50],
    remote: "php_validation_scripts/check_first_name_field.php"
}
}})
```

Comment: `.ready()` is used to ensure your JS doesn't execute until your DOM is ready. This is why it fails outside of it. Your DOM isn't fully loaded, so the event doesn't know all of your elements. I would say it is required.

Comment: You can swap `$(document).ready(function(){` with `$(function(){`. I would also move your custom functions outside of the ready block.

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Drew and others, I appreciate your suggestions. The problem is that when the code is inside of the .ready() function it requires 2 clicks in order to get through(the user has to press the submit button twice).

Comment: I get one error.  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/